# Multiple OSs in one box

Tags: ubuntu, windows-vista, partitioning, multi-boot

I have a Windows Vista Box running Ubuntu 9.10 (with multiple kernel images) in another partition.
Now, I'd like to install Ubuntu 11.10 beta too so it can coexist with the other two. Are there any considerations to have so the other OSs remain intact ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just make sure you partition your drive as recommended for the OS in question and install on the proper partition. Install the boot-loader (GRUB2) for Ubuntu on the partition which is mounted at `/` and then add an entry in the Windows boot loader to point to the new partition.

I had problems with installing Ubuntu after Windows, GRUB was installed on the Windows partition and then Windows "corrected" this by re-installing the Windows boot screen. I ended up adding an entry to the Windows boot configuration which points to the new Ubuntu partition and it is working fine.

**Be careful!**